# Unnamed column and Nan in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

i'm getting Unnamed and Nan in output when i try to print the headers of .csv file.

import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.read_csv('testextract.csv', error_bad_lines=False,sep=' ',dtype=unicode,index_col=0,low_memory=False)
print(df.head())
```

Output :

```
 Unnamed: 1 Unnamed: 2 Unnamed: 3 Unnamed: 4 Unnamed: 5 Unnamed: 6  \
��T                                                                     
NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
```

Comment: Is your separator (sep='') empty? That's going to cause some problems! I see you've just edited and it isn't empty so ignore this comment.

Comment: You should show us a sample of your input csv for us to have a chance.

Comment: Please read the index column while reading the csv file, if you are storing, and reading multiple times same csv without mentioning index column, 'Unnamed' columns will generate and store the index information for each saving('to_csv" function).

Answer (score 2):

Use '~'(Bitwise NOT) operator to fetch whole rows from dataframe without columns which named as 'Unnamed'.

```
  data = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.contains('^Unnamed')]
  print(data)
```

Comment: Please do some explanation for the answer

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading a csv file and using the separater as ' '.
Use the below code
pd.read_csv(file_name,encoding = 'UTF-8')

Comment: not working..TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 0 found

Answer (score 0):

I've come across the same error. You have to change your encoding to ensure it's UTF-8. You can do this two ways:

1. Use the encoding method from Pandas i.e. for your example:

```
df = pd.read_csv('testextract.csv', encoding, errors='strict')
```

2. Open the CSV file in a spreadsheet application and save as in UTF-8. Then, run your code again.

Hope this helps.